# why is a comma used before "contents"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw the following snippet in a jquery code, but I don't understand why it uses a comma right before 'contents' instead of a period.

```
var that = $(this),
contents = that.serialize();
```

Does anyone have an idea why a comma is being used?

I am missing the words to search properly I think.

Comment: "Comma Trick" reference: http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/javascript-comma-trick.html

Comment: `var`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 4):

same as :

```
var that = $(this);
var contents = that.serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks alot you both, I am new to this thanks! Sorry if this was a duplicate, but without the proper knowledge this is hard for a newbie to see.

Answer (score 4):

You can use it to declare multiple variables, it's just shorthand for:

```
var that = $(this);
var contents = that.serialize();
```

Many other languages support the same.

Comment: haha was 1s faster :p

Comment: LOL +1 to you anyway, what's 1 second hey? :)

Comment: true, maybe 25rep? :p

Comment: @mattytommo -- inch or a mile my friend :D

Comment: Thank you also for answering